# WFS layer in openlayers not showing up in the database

Tags: database, postgresql, web-services, post, geoserver

i am setting up a PostgreSQL/Geoserver/Openlayers application. I am able to fetch a data from postgreSQL thorugh Geoserver as a layer and display it above openlayers map in my web application but **when i try creating a polygon on the openlayers map and store it in the database i am unable to do so**. The creation of polygon works fine but nothing happens after that and i cant see it stored anywhere and when i refresh the page its gone. Probably my Post query is not working fine. Here is my code with GET and POST queries. **How can i store a polygon in the database?**

```
var formatWFS = new ol.format.WFS();
var formatGML = new ol.format.GML({
    featureNS: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/DBdata/wfs',
    featureType: 'wfs_geom',
    srsName: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var s = new XMLSerializer();

var sourceWFS = new ol.source.Vector({
    loader: function (extent) {
        $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/DBdata/wfs', {
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                service: 'WFS',
                version: '1.1.0',
                request: 'GetFeature',
                typename: 'DBdata:district',
                srsname: 'EPSG:3857',
                bbox: extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857'
            }
        }).done(function (response) {
            sourceWFS.addFeatures(formatWFS.readFeatures(response));
        });
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
    projection: 'EPSG:3857'
});

var layerWFS = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: sourceWFS
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
         }),
        layerWFS
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([71,30]),
        zoom: 4
    })
});

var interaction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    type: 'Polygon',
    source: layerWFS.getSource()
});

map.addInteraction(interaction);

interaction.on('drawend', function (e) {
    $.ajax('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/DBdata/wfs', {
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'xml',
        contentType: 'text/xml',
        data: s.serializeToString(formatWFS.writeTransaction([e.feature], null, null, formatGML))
    }).done();
});


function switchlayer(thelayer){
          var layer= {
             
              districtwfs:layerWFS,
              
          }
          [thelayer];
          layer.setVisible(!layer.getVisible());
          return layer;
      }
```

**Geoserver log**

```
    Request: getFeature service = WFS version = 1.1.0 baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ query[0]: filter = [ bbox ReferencedEnvelope[3158473.130378682 : 1.2648894562266165E7, 1546761.9194038615 : 5460337.767604887] ] srsName = EPSG:3857 typeName[0] = {http://geoserver.org/DBdata}district outputFormat = text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1 resultType = results 2020-12-28 21:54:01,553 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - Request: getServiceInfo 2020-12-28 21:54:01,570 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - org.geoserver.wfs.WFSException: No such feature type http://localhost:8080/geoserver/DBdata/wfs:district at org.geoserver.wfs.WFSWorkspaceQualifier.ensureFeatureNamespaceUriMatches(WFSWorkspaceQualifier.java:215) at org.geoserver.wfs.WFSWorkspaceQualifier.qualifyRequest(WFSWorkspaceQualifier.java:192) at org.geoserver.ows.WorkspaceQualifyingCallback.operationDispatched(WorkspaceQualifyingCallback.java:49) at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.fireOperationDispatchedCallback(Dispatcher.java:830)
```

Response

```
    <ows:ExceptionReport
     
    xmlns:xs
    ="
    http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
    "
     
    xmlns:ows
    ="
    http://www.opengis.net/ows
    "
     
    xmlns:xsi
    ="
    http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
    "
     
    version
    ="
    1.0.0
    "
     
    xsi:schemaLocation
    ="
    http://www.opengis.net/ows http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd
    "
    >
    <ows:Exception
     
    exceptionCode
    ="
    NoApplicableCode
    "
    >
    <ows:ExceptionText
    >
    No such feature type http://localhost:8080/geoserver/DBdata/wfs:district
    </ows:ExceptionText
    >
    </ows:Exception>
    </ows:ExceptionReport>
```

Comment: please add the XML sent to geoserver and the response that is returned, there is probably also useful information in the geoserver log file

Comment: @IanTurton how caan i access that?

Comment: the request and response will show in the debugger network tab and the GeoServer log is in the data_dir/logs folder

Comment: @IanTurton i have added the responses from Geoserver and network tab

Comment: @IanTurton i have already specified `featureNS`. My WFS GET request is working fine, it's the POST query that is not working if you llok at the code in question . i have mentioned both the quesries

Comment: the point remains that GeoServer doesn't see that NS see the error message and the log file

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the response and the log file:

```
No such feature type http://localhost:8080/geoserver/DBdata/wfs:district
```

You are requesting a feature that doesn't exist.

I suspect that you don't want the `wfs:` in the name or you have misspecified the NameSpace URL of the featureType.

When I look at the [OpenLayers WFS example page](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/vector-wfs-getfeature.html) I get:

// generate a GetFeature request

```
var featureRequest = new WFS().writeGetFeature({
  srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
  featureNS: 'http://openstreemap.org',
  featurePrefix: 'osm',
  featureTypes: ['water_areas'],
  outputFormat: 'application/json',
  filter: andFilter(
    likeFilter('name', 'Mississippi*'),
    equalToFilter('waterway', 'riverbank')
  ),
});
```

Whereas you don't specify a `featureNS` or a `featurePrefix` which probably why they get filled in wrong in the request.